# SQL Server 2012 Browser Service doesn't appear

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've installed SQL Server 2012 and Management Studio Express. I attached the database that belongs my previous Project in Visual Studio. But I am having SqlException Error , I think the reason of the error is SQL Server. Because when I look at active services, I only see SQL Server VSS Writer. I can't see SQL Server Browser Service and other SQL Server services. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Log file:

```
  Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Passed
  Exit code (Decimal):           0
  Start time:                    2014-07-27 21:42:30
  End time:                      2014-07-27 21:45:33
  Requested action:              Patch

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  KEREM
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Future Windows Version
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     Türkiye
  OS language:                   Türkçe (Türkiye)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Express Edition      11.0.2100.60    No        
  SQL Server 2012                                                          LocalDB                                  1033                 Express Edition      11.1.3000.0     No        

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2012
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       11
  SPLevel:                       1
  KBArticle:                     KB2674319
  KBArticleHyperlink:            http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2674319
  PatchType:                     SP
  AssociatedHotfixBuild:         0
  Platform:                      x64
  PatchLevel:                    11.1.3000.0
  ProductVersion:                11.0.2100.60
  GDRReservedRange:              10.0.1000.0:10.0.1099.0;10.0.3000.0:10.0.3099.0
  PackageName:                   SQLServer2012-KB2674319-x64.exe
```

Comment: You haven't installed SQL Server. You have only installed SSMS.

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith No, I have installed. To be sure, I've checked it.

Comment: Can you post log file(summary.txt) generated after installation. Location would be C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log

Comment: @Shanky I edited the question.

Comment: @KeremZaman how did you check it?

Comment: "But I am having SqlException Error" that is not a useful error description. What did you conclude of that exception?

Comment: @usr I have checked if Microsoft SQL Server 2012 is in the Programs and Features list.

Comment: Exception's description is :SqlException was unhandled by user code.An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Log you posted seems incomplete, also it is not the log for SQL Server installation but for patch update. You can see in the log

```
Requested action:   Patch
```

Anyways log is helpful because it shows below

```
Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Express Edition      11.0.2100.60    No        
  SQL Server 2012                                                          LocalDB                                  1033                 Express Edition      11.1.3000.0     No
```

Whenever you run patch SQL Server writes in Log what all instances and features it has found on the current system and as per log you only installed

1. SQL Server management studio
2. Local DB not Database engine.

You need to download **ENU\x64\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe** because your system is 64 bit from [This Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

I am not sure error is because of missing Browser or missing Express Database Engine service. Browser service is installed with SQL Express database engine so if you are looking to connect to database engine not Local DB you need to to install Express DB engine.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed SQL Server. You have only installed SSMS.

> I have checked if Microsoft SQL Server 2012 is in the Programs and Features list.

This means that *any* SQL Server feature is installed. SSMS is one such feature.

> Exception's description is :SqlException was unhandled by user code.An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

This is still not a useful problem description. Analyzing the *full* error message is always the first step in diagnosing an error. Error message are written to point the developer to the cause of the error. You haven't even read the full exception.

Anyway, I hope this resolves the problem. Restart SQL Server setup and add the "Database Engine" feature.